# How to access context.globalState inside a refresh() function of a TreeView class?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, treeview, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to access `context.globalState.get('data');` inside a TreeView refresh() function.
My `refresh()` looks like this:

```
    refresh(offset?: number): void {
        this.ctmInfrastructureCache = getGlobalStateData();
        this.parseTree();
        if (offset) {
            this._onDidChangeTreeData.fire(offset);
        } else {
            this._onDidChangeTreeData.fire(undefined);
        }

    }
```

The global state data is supposed to be provided by:

```
export function getGlobalStateData(): string {
    const data: string = context.globalState.get('ctmInfrastructureCache');
    return data;
}
```

However, I can't access context.globalState. I'm getting:

> Property 'globalState' does not exist on type 'SuiteFunction'.ts(2339)

The new data is collected before refresh is being called and assigned to a globalState context. All I want is to get the data and provide it as input for the new TreeView.

I've tried adding `context: vscode.ExtensionContext` to the `refresh()` to no avail.
How do I get access to `globalState` inside the refresh?

The class constructor() has access to globalState. This is working:

```
    constructor(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
        let ctmInfrastructureCacheTmp: any = context.globalState.get('ctmInfrastructureCache');
        let ctmInfrastructureCacheType: any = typeof ctmInfrastructureCacheTmp;

        // check if json needs to be converted
        if (ctmInfrastructureCacheType === "string") {
            this.ctmInfrastructureCache = ctmInfrastructureCacheTmp;
        } else {
            this.ctmInfrastructureCache = JSON.stringify(ctmInfrastructureCacheTmp);
        }
        this.parseTree();
    }
```

Comment: `this._onDidChangeTreeData.fire(offset ? offset : undefined);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are missing is that the context is passed to the constructor, so it has access to it there. In your `getGlobalStateData()` function `context` is not known. The reference to `context` probably references a different context object.

One possible solution is to keep a reference to `context` and use it as member of the class:

```
    public constructor(private context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
        let ctmInfrastructureCacheTmp: any = context.globalState.get('ctmInfrastructureCache');
        let ctmInfrastructureCacheType: any = typeof ctmInfrastructureCacheTmp;

        // check if json needs to be converted
        if (ctmInfrastructureCacheType === "string") {
            this.ctmInfrastructureCache = ctmInfrastructureCacheTmp;
        } else {
            this.ctmInfrastructureCache = JSON.stringify(ctmInfrastructureCacheTmp);
        }
        this.parseTree();
    }

    public refresh(offset?: number): void {
        this.ctmInfrastructureCache = this.context.globalState.get('ctmInfrastructureCache');
        this.parseTree();
        if (offset) {
            this._onDidChangeTreeData.fire(offset);
        } else {
            this._onDidChangeTreeData.fire(undefined);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

based on Mike's suggestions I've updated the code and it works now.
First I've added the 'context' to the registerCommand() section of my refresh().

```
ctmInfrastructureProvider.refresh(undefined, context);
```

Then I've updated the refresh function like this, with 'context?: vscode.ExtensionContext' as an optional input.

```
    public refresh(offset?: number, context?: vscode.ExtensionContext): void {
        // get globalState data
        let ctmInfrastructureCacheTmp: any = context.globalState.get('ctmInfrastructureCache');
        let ctmInfrastructureCacheType: any = typeof ctmInfrastructureCacheTmp;

        // check if json needs to be converted
        if (ctmInfrastructureCacheType === "string") {
            this.ctmInfrastructureCache = ctmInfrastructureCacheTmp;
        } else {
            this.ctmInfrastructureCache = JSON.stringify(ctmInfrastructureCacheTmp);
        }

        this.parseTree();
        if (offset) {
            this._onDidChangeTreeData.fire(offset);
        } else {
            this._onDidChangeTreeData.fire(undefined);
        }

    }
```

Regards, O.